# $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\partial \Omega$ then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\bar{\Omega}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, uniform-convergence

The problem states that $f_n$ is a sequence of functions which are continuous on the closure of $\Omega$ and holomorphic on $\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded region and were asked to show that if $f_n$ converges uniformly on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ then it converges uniformly on the closure.

So I was hoping someone could check my work. This is what I have so far:

Let $z$ be in the closure of $\Omega$. If $z\in \partial \Omega$ then there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, we can write $$f_n(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{f_n(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$$ and now pass to the limit $$f(x)=\lim \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{f_n(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$$ then, by the uniform convergence of $f_n$ on the boundary, the limit can be taken inside the integral. Is this all that needs to be said?

Comment: No. First, you can't necessarily write $f$ as that integral; you'd need to know that $\partial \Omega$ was a nice enough curve and that hypotheses about winding numbers were satisfied. But even if $\Omega$ is a disk or something, that argument shows that $f_n\to f$ pointwise in $\Omega$, but not uniformly. Hint for a simple correct proof: Maximum Modulus Theorem.

Comment: I don't think I see how to apply the maximum modulus principle correctly here, but heres my attempt:  Each $f_n$ is holomorphic and therefore the sup of $f_n$ is at the boundary for each $n$. Let $M_n$ be the sequence of the sups. Then since $f_n$ converges uniformly on the boundary, $M_n$ converges to some $M$ and so there is a subsequence of $f_n$ bounded uniformly by $M$? from here I'm lost :(

Comment: Apply MMT to $f-f_n$...

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Omega$ is bounded, we can use the maximum modulus principle. For each $m,n$ we have that $f_n-f_m$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and is continuous on the boundary. Therefore, $$\sup_{\overline{\Omega}} |f_n-f_m|=\sup_{\partial{\Omega}} |f_n-f_m|.$$ Since the $f_n$ converge uniformly on $\partial{\Omega}$, the right hand side is small for $m,n$ large. Therefore, the $f_n$ are uniformly Cauchy on $\overline{\Omega}$ and hence converge uniformly there.